# Input and output recursive java Scanner

Tags: java, recursion

I seem to be having a really hard time understanding input and output of text files. I'm not sure on how I'd implement my input text file in the two recursive methods that I created. Should I be creating the text file inside of the constructor? Any help would be really appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

/**
 * @author (Matt Mastell)
 * @version (3/14/15)
 */
public class CS152 {
    static final int MAXSIZE = 22;
    private static int size = 0;
    ArrayList<Student> Slist = new ArrayList<Student>(MAXSIZE);

    Scanner scann = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));

    public static Student[] createList(Scanner scan) {
        Student[] list = new Student[MAXSIZE];
        return populateList(list, scan);
    }

    private static Student[] populateList(Student[] list, Scanner scan) {
        Student s;
        if (size < MAXSIZE && scan.hasNext()) {
            s = new Student(scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.next(),
                    scan.nextDouble(), scan.nextInt());
            list[size] = s;
            size++;
            return populateList(list, scan);
        }
        else {
            return list;
        }
    }

    public static int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

Comment: Expected/actual output?

Comment: I note that you have an instance field Scanner, but your methods are static and take a Scanner argument. I suggest you pick one.

Comment: Elliott do I just create a scanner variable in my main class?

Comment: Adrian the output would be; all students, honors students, number of honors students, and who the honor students are.

Comment: public class TestStudents
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        CS152 cs = new CS152();
        ArrayList<Student> Slist = cs.getStudents();
        Scanner scann = new Scanner (new File("input.txt"));
        
        cs.populateList(Slist, scann);
    }
}This is what I managed for the main test class yet I get incompatible type error